# python - ValueError: time data does not match format

Tags: python, csv, numpy, date-conversion

I downloaded my CSV file TSLA.csv from [here](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/history?period1=1277762400&period2=1504735200&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d). It has a header line and 7 columns, first of which is date, the others are floats and ints.

I want to be able to get a numpy array out of it:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import urllib


def bytespdate2num(fmt, encoding="utf-8"):
    strconverter = mdates.strpdate2num(fmt)
    def bytesconverter(b): 
        s = b.decode(encoding)
        return strconverter(s)
    return bytesconverter

with open("TSLA.CSV", "r") as csvfile:
    stock_price = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=" ")
    stock_price = list(stock_price)


date, closep, highp, lowp, openp, volume = np.loadtxt(stock_price, 
                                                      delimiter = ",",
                                                      unpack = True,
                                                      skiprows=1,
                                                      converters={0: bytespdate2num("%Y-%m-%d")})
```

Trouble is, I get the following error:

> ValueError: time data "['2010-06-29" does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

I have double-checked the format and checked other questions around here, but those were mostly about the wrong format... I can't see the problem here. Help appreciated.

Comment: Is this the complete code? I can't see where you are actually using the format string in the code. Can you add that too?

Comment: @KshitijMittal, the format string is in the last row of the code and passed to the bytespdate2num function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I believe the problem is here:

Have a look again at the error, it says `"['2010-06-29" does not match data format`. 
That is because you are not trying to parse the date alone, look at the double quotes that surround the date.

You are trying to parse:

```
['2010-06-29
```

There's an extra `['` in your string that is messing things up.

Comment: Don't even worry, those things happen. At first, I was thinking the same you did. It took me a while to realise.