# python - converting strings from csv to date and float formats

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, datetime

Continuing on my previous problem with time data not matching the provided format ([python - ValueError: time data does not match format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090981/python-valueerror-time-data-does-not-match-format)), I need help with converting string to data.

I downloaded my CSV file from [here](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/history?period1=1277762400&period2=1504735200&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d). It has a header line and 7 columns, first of which represents date, the others numbers.

First data line converted to list looks like this:

```
['2010-06-29', '19.000000', '25.000000', '17.540001', '23.889999', '23.889999', '18766300']
```

I want to be able to get a numpy array out of it:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import urllib

def bytespdate2num(fmt, encoding="utf-8"):
    strconverter = mdates.strpdate2num(fmt)
    def bytesconverter(b): 
        s = b.decode(encoding)
        return strconverter(s)
    return bytesconverter

with open("TSLA.CSV", "r") as csvfile:
    stock_price = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    stock_price = list(stock_price)

date, closep, highp, lowp, openp, volume = np.loadtxt(stock_price, 
                                                      delimiter = ",",
                                                      unpack = True,
                                                      skiprows=1,
                                                      # '2010-06-29'
                                                      converters={0: bytespdate2num("['%Y-%m-%d'")}
                                                      )
```

Trouble is, I get the following error:

> ValueError: time data "['2010-06-29" does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

The issue is the `['` before the date. I tried iterating over the items in the column and replacing [' with ""; didn't work. Then I tried to give format `"['%Y-%m-%d'"` just to see what would happen. That got around that error (although I'm not happy with that solution, of course), but there was another one:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: b' 18766300.0]'

I googled and searched on here but found nothing...

Comment: Do you have pandas?

Comment: I do; how would you go about solving this with it?

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` could be used as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

def bytespdate2num(x):
    return mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))

df = np.genfromtxt('TSLA.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1, converters={0: bytespdate2num}, dtype='int')
```

You would need to decide on a suitable type to store all numbers in. Pandas would probably be a better match though.

`df` would then appear as:

```
[( 733952.,  19,  25,  17,  23,  23, 18766300)
 ( 733953.,  25,  30,  23,  23,  23, 17187100)
 ( 733954.,  25,  25,  20,  21,  21,  8218800) ...,
 ( 736573., 356, 357, 353, 355, 355,  3049500)
 ( 736577., 353, 355, 345, 349, 349,  3835100)
 ( 736578., 349, 350, 341, 344, 344,  4079000)]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the pandas library as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv("TSLA.CSV")

date = dataset['Date']
# etc.
```

Reference: [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)